# Modals appear with shading overlay, controls unusable #31

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, twitter-bootstrap-4

I am trying to use a modal opened by a button. Eventually, it will be a form. But, for now, just any kind of basic modal test would be a success.

The problem is, every modal is appearing with the shading not just behind it but also over the front. That means everything on the page (both the modal and the page behind) is unclickable.

Here is my code - https://www.pastiebin.com/593c55bebedd8

FYI, this is being run through WordPress, with navbar content (bearing the button in question) run through bs4navbar - but I also get the problem when I hand-code the modal code direct.

I'm curious to know what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is HTML code for your modal is inside nav element. Move your modal HTML part to just before `</body>` or somewhere on root body level and everything will be fine.